# Linux - Convert FAT32 to NTFS without loss data

Tags: linux, filesystems, ntfs, fat32

I have an external USB hard disk (300GB) in FAT32. The question is how can I convert the type FAT32 to NTFS without loss my data. I have 250 GB of data stored in my disk.

I was trying to do that in windows with Acronis and the native command windows convert, but neither can do. I think maybe was for the big size of data.

I hope someone can guide me a little.

Comment: Can you add which error message you got when you tried to use convert.exe in windows?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the data safe and do serious filesystem manipulation (which converting the FS certainly is), then first make a backup. Then test the backup.

Next you have three choices:

1. Boot windows (e.g. use someones computer) and use `convert Driveletter: /fs:ntfs`.  (See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307881 for more details).
2. Reformat the drive. You already have a known good backup and this is likely to be the fastest option. Then restore the data.
3. Find some utility which lets you convert under Linux. I never heard of one though and some quick googling did not find any.

Comment: @terdon - My last comment was misleading in the slightest.

Comment: `convert.exe` is risky. It is the same type of risk for all _in-place_ filesystem conversion tools -- that _if your computer's power cut, then the drive will be in unusable state_. It cannot be made anyway safer, so while you can, backup all the data and copy it to a newly formatted drive! By the way, it's very unlikely that someone will write a convert.exe utility for Linux because of the aforementioned risk...

Comment: I agree. Hence the `first make a backup`.  Which actually should have been `make a fresh new backup, which is 100% up to date` just to prevent confusion with hopefully already existing other backups.